# @If dentro de uma tag <body>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Como colocar uma condição `if` dentro de uma tag `<body>`?

Ao tentar fazer:

```
@if (Request.Path.Substring(Request.Path.LastIndexOf("/") + 1).ToLower() == "default") {
    <body class="home"
} else {
    <body>
}
```

Ele não executa pois não tem uma tag `</body>` junto. Se fosse uma cláusula `<p></p>` ele funcionaria, porém como a tag de fechamento `</body>` não pode estar junto ele não deixa executar.

Ao tentar fazer um:

```
<body @if (Request.Path.Substring(Request.Path.LastIndexOf("/") + 1).ToLower() == "default") { Response.Write("class='home'"); } >
```

Também não chega nem perto de querer funcionar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se quiser deixar o código HTML um pouco mais claro, pode separar a condição em um bloco a parte e declarar uma variável nele com o valor do atributo:

```
@{ 
    string bodyAttr = String.Empty;
    if(Request.Path.Substring(Request.Path.LastIndexOf("/") + 1).ToLower() == "default")
        bodyAttr = "class=home";        
}
<body @bodyAttr>
```

---

<sub>*Observação*: Nos meus testes, usando o ASP.NET MVC 5, o valor do atributo não precisa ser colocado entre aspas. Usando `bodyAttr = "class='home'"` o HTML gerado foi `<body class="'home'">` (**com aspas simples a mais**). Quando uso `bodyAttr = "class=home"` o HTML é `bodyAttr = "class=home"`. Não sei como é o comportamento em versões anteriores do MVC.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Experimente usar [o operador ternário](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) de forma parecida com a segunda forma:

```
<body @{Request.Path.Substring(Request.Path.LastIndexOf("/") + 1).ToLower() == "default" ? "class='home'" : "";}>
```

Comment: Apresentou o erro: "; expected"

Comment: @Dorathoto Faltou um ponto-e-vírgula no final. Editei a resposta.